# Sql raise error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

table contains a record of `name` `salary`

like this
I want a deduction of 5000 from every employee.  If the `salary < 0` then i need to display **"insuffiecient for deduction"** if `salary > 0` then **" can be deducted"**

This is the images of the table.

[image]

Comment: What table? Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question.

Comment: Update your question with the table structure to help you better. What query did you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, i have added case when, which will help you.

**Note:** you can add the field as per your requirement

```
SELECT Emno, EmName, 
       CASE WHEN sal < 0 THEN "insuffiecient for deduction" 
            ELSE "can be deducted" END As Status 
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the query below:

```
SELECT `name`, `sal`,  IF((`sal`-5000)<0,'insufficient for deduction','can be deducted') AS `status` FROM `employee`;
```

I only use the `name` and `sal` field since this two fields are only needed to solve your problem. The formula used was:

```
(`sal`-5000)<0
```

which means that the salary of certain employee will be deducted by 5000 and then immediately compare if it's negative or positive. If the result is negative it means that it's 'insufficient for deduction' else 'can be deducted'.

Comment: It works fine on me. Oh well. whatever. I'm just giving you idea.